# Ember: How to use link-to inside a component

Tags: ember.js

I have a component that contains a link-to. The component is more complicated, but for simplicity here:

```
//Component.hbs
{{#link-to link model}}{{yield}}{{/link-to}}
```

The problem is sometimes I will pass a model, sometimes I will not.

```
//Route.hbs
//providing the model
{{my-component link='chosenroute' model='chosenmodel'}}

//omitting a model - doesn't work
{{my-component link='otherroute'}}
```

How do I make the model argument optional?

Comment: I dont get this line {{my-component link model}} -  provide some code or use case. it would be helpful to provide answer

Comment: Thanks, that was more than a typo. Hope this makes sense now.

Comment: if you are using dynamic segments, then you can pass id instead of model. {{#link-to 'home' (if model 1 2) }}  {{yield}} {{/link-to}}...this will force model hook to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put an if/else. `undefined` is not a good parameter for link-to.

//Component.hbs

```
{{#if model}}
    {{#link-to link model}}{{yield}}{{/link-to}}
{{else}}
    {{#link-to link}}{{yield}}{{/link-to}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: I think I was looking for something far more complicated... thanks!